# Surface tension in water

Tags: pressure, surface-tension

The force of surface tension acts tangential to the surface where residents the force due to air pressure acts perpendicularly on the surface. How is then the force due to excess pressure inside a bubble balanced by the force due to the surface tension?

Anybody help me out for this problem

Answer (score 1):

The excess internal pressure forces the bubble to expand, thus increasing the surface area of the bubble. This stretching of the surface causes a tangential strain that is then balanced by the surface tension.